Maximal Families of Cyclic Projections
This is a remark out of a textbook I'm reading through that I can't seem to figure out.
Let $A \subset B(H)$ a $C^{*}$-algebra act non-degenerately on a Hilbert space $H$.  Given $h \in H$ a unit vector, we define $[Ah]$ to be the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $\overline{Ah}$.  This is what I mean by a cyclic projection (with cyclic vector $h$ in this case).
The author then states that via a Zorn's lemma argument and using the non-degeneracy of $A$ in $B(H)$ that we can get a 'maximal family of cyclic projections for $A$', call it $(P_i)_{i \in I}$ such that the family is mutually orthogonal and such that $\sum_i P_i$ converges in the strong operator topology to the unit $1_H$.  Moreover they claim that since any cyclic projection $P$ of $A$ lies in the commutant $A'$ that $\sup_i \lVert TP_i \rVert = \lVert T \rVert$.
I'm having trouble showing these two claims.

I can show easily there is a maximal family of orthogonal projections having the desired property, but they aren't cyclic. I would really appreciate someone showing me how to apply Zorn's lemma correctly here.

Regarding the sup equality, I don't really see how knowing each such projection being in the commutant of $A$ actually does anything.  Obviously $\sup_i \lVert TP_i \rVert \leq \lVert T \rVert$ but for the other direction:  $$\lVert T \rVert^2 = \sup_{\lVert h \rVert = 1} \lVert Th \rVert^2 = \sup_{\lVert h \rVert=1} \left(\sum_i \lVert P_iTh \rVert^2 \right) = \sup_{\lVert h \rVert=1} \left(\sum_i \lVert TP_ih \rVert^2 \right)...?$$ and after this I'm not sure how to proceed.



For the first claim, the Zorn's lemma part of the argument is no different from what you would do to obtain a maximal family of orthogonal projections - let $S$ be the poset whose elements are families of mutually orthogonal, nonzero cyclic projections, ordered by set inclusion. Then it is clear that any chain has a supremum (namely the union of the chain), whence by Zorn's lemma you get a maximal family of mutually orthogonal cyclic projections $(P_i)_{i \in I}$. The only thing here is to check $\sum_i P_i = 1_H$. Indeed, assume to the contrary. Then $\oplus_i P_iH \neq H$, so we may choose nonzero $h \in H$ s.t. $P_iH \perp h$ for all $i$. By non-degeneracy, $\overline{Ah} \neq 0$, so we just need to check $P_iH \perp \overline{Ah}$. Indeed, $P_iH = \overline{Ak}$ for some $k \in H$ itself, so, for any $a, b \in A$,
$$\langle ak, bh \rangle = \langle b^\ast ak, h \rangle = 0$$
as $b^\ast a \in A$ and $h \perp Ak$. Thus, $Ak \perp Ah$. Taking limits yield $P_iH = \overline{Ak} \perp \overline{Ah}$. So adding $[Ah]$ to $(P_i)_{i \in I}$ gives a family of mutually orthogonal, nonzero cyclic projections, contradicting maximality of $(P_i)_{i \in I}$.
For the second claim, you're nearly there. Continuing your calculations:
$$\begin{split}
\|T\|^2 &= \sup_{\|h\| = 1} (\sum_i \|TP_ih\|^2)\\
&= \sup_{\|h\| = 1} (\sum_i \|TP_iP_ih\|^2)\\
&\leq \sup_i \|TP_i\|^2 \sup_{\|h\| = 1} (\sum_i \|P_ih\|^2)\\
&= \sup_i \|TP_i\|^2 \sup_{\|h\| = 1} \|h\|^2\\
&= \sup_i \|TP_i\|^2
\end{split}$$
Taking square roots yields $\|T\| = \sup_i \|TP_i\|$.
For intuition of what's happening, $P_i$ commuting with $T$ ensures that $P_iT = P_iTP_i = TP_i$. This means $T$ sends $P_iH$ to $P_iH$ for all $i$, so $T$ can be written in block diagonal form as $\oplus_i TP_i$ acting on $\oplus_i P_iH = H$. From this description it is easy to see that $\|T\| = \sup_i \|TP_i\|$.
